# pandas DF column max difference between pair of values recursively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I have a DataFrame with a column 'col1' with integers in it.
The DF may have anything from 100 up to 1mln rows.
How to compute difference between pair of values in the col1 such as:

row2 - row1
row3 - row2
row4 - row3
etc

and return max difference?

I know how to use loc, iloc but do not know how to force it to go through pair of values and move to next pair

Comment: `df['col1'].diff().max()`?

Comment: I missed the pairing... yeah, what @JohnGalt said.

Comment: Arghh.... how hard is it to tag PYTHON, when this is for PYTHON language?

Comment: Is it all pairs or just consecutive pairs?

Answer (score 1):

```
max(df[col_name].shift(-1)-df[col_name])
```

The function shift takes the value of the next row (or second next row if you take do shift(-2)). By doing df[col_name].shift(-1), you take for a certain row, the value which is in the row below it. Substracting the value from the current from the value from df[col_name].shift(-1) gives you per row the difference between rows. So in a dataframe you'll end up with series of difference between rows. Take the max and you get the max.

```
Example below col_1 == Original column, col_2 == df[col_1].shift(-1)


> col_1 |  col_2 
> 123 | 456
> 456| 999
> 999| nan
```

Now you just substract col_1 from col_2, take the max and get the max difference.

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: The function shift takes the value of the next row (or second next row if you take do shift(-2)). By doing df[col_name].shift(-1), you take for a certain row, the value which is in the row below it. Substracting the value from the current from the value from df[col_name].shift(-1) gives you per row the difference between rows. So in a dataframe you'll end up with series of difference between rows. Take the max and you get the max.

Comment: Thats good. I think its better if you edit your answer and add this explanation there.

Comment: I'll remember it, thanks for the advice.